# sfmc-fuelsdk-node - Retrive All DataExtension including Child BU : MemberID does not have access to ClientID

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

Building a Custom Activity, here I am using sfmc-fuelsdk-node npm package.

SFMC account is a Enterprise account, I am are trying to retrieve all DE including Child BU and getting a error as "MemberID XXXXXXXX does not have access to ClientID XXXXXXXX".

MemberID - Parent BU
ClientID - Child BU

When I use Parent BU ID as ClientID, I am able to retrieve DE, but not those that are under childBU. To retreive ChildBU DE's, used ClientId as ChildID with Parent BU AccessToken.

Can someone suggest me a solution related to this error [node].

Comment: Are you using Oauth2.0 authentication or is your process still based on a "legacy" API connection?
 (check the installed package in Marketing Cloud & refer to the code here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfmc-fuelsdk-node - underneath the mention of "tenant-specific endpoints")

Comment: I've not used the library, but the NPM you're using doesn't appear to provide the capability to pass the "QueryAllAccounts" directive through to the underlying SOAP library it's basing itself on - https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-SOAP. Try using this lower level library that purports to support what you're trying to do - QueryAllAccounts.

Answer (score 0):

Each BU has it's own

ClientID/ClientSecret

Check on each BU separately on 
Setup >  Apps > Installed Packages

You should see there listed the different BUs.

Click on the particular one you are looking for and retrieve from the correct API keys.

Comment: with the oAuth 2.0 you can use one clientid/secret between bu you just need to pass AccountID in the call

Comment: @EazyE : I have used Fuel C# SDK, where we pass the leacytoken and there are no issues. The problem is in custom activity we are using SFMC FUEL NODE npm package - is there a way to pass the legacy token instead of accesstoken?